# Issue with the serial port in Qt and Windows: qwineventnotifier

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qextserialport

I have a problem in Qt -> C++.  I need to open the serial port of a rover in Qt, and I downloaded the library "qextserialport-1.2rc".  In Linux it's all okay, but in Windows 7 there is an error (it doesn't find a file called "qwineventnotifier").

I tried to download this file, but this didn't resolved the problem: there is still an error when I try to include the library "qextserialport".

Thanks, Matt

Edit: The error is: QtCore/private/qwineventnotifier_p.h:No such file or directory

Comment: Please note the error messages, that will help use to identify your problem.

Comment: I can't put an image because I haven't 10 of reputation, I think: so I wrote the error. Thanks

Comment: To open serial port and perform actions, I used `QtSerialPort` which gave me no problem on both win32 and linux. You can give a try to this repository `git://gitorious.org/qt/qtserialport.git`

Comment: Muhammad, please can you give me some instructions? Shall I copy your link (git://...) on git bash? I tried, but he told me that it couldn't download anything!

Comment: Simply do `git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qtserialport.git` and then `qmake; make; make install`.

Comment: @JoeMatt: have you tried using QtSerialPort?